# getting the users instagram posts api in laravel php

Tags: php, laravel, instagram

i simply want to take users post in my laravel application . its even fine if my user has to insert his username password because i want to crawl all the posts media and text once and then they can change password .
for the matter of what i tried so far :
1-i created an app in this link :

```
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
```

then i generates an `User Token`  and a `App Token` after that i called this api :

```
https://graph.instagram.com/17841405793187218?fields=id,username&access_token=myAppToken
```

i placed my App token in that api but this showed me this error :

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Access token does not contain a valid app ID",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 190,
        "fbtrace_id": "Agc0R_wnDwoCzgNuXt2gt1y"
    }
}
```

now i dont know even if i am on a right train or not but simply i want to crawl all users posts . thanks in advance

Comment: "Access token does not contain a valid app ID" seems pretty clear. Sounds like you didn't set up something properly on the server side.

Comment: you can try Laravel Socialite (composer require laravel/socialite)

Comment: Have you followed the instructions on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-access-tokens-and-permissions to get an `access_token` for your user?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Laravel Socialite since it will simplify the whole process.
Follow the installation instructions here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/socialite
Don't forget to put the fb credentials in your `config/service.php` like so:

```
 'facebook'        => [
        'client_id'     => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect'      => env('FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URL'),
    ],
```

Now that we have set up Socialite to work with Facebook, we should redirect the user to the facebook login page where it will enter his credentials.
Define the login route:

```
 Route::get('facebook', 'FacebookLoginController@redirectToProvider');
```

Define the controller and the method:

```
class FacebookLoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Redirect the user to the FB authentication page.
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function redirectToProvider(RedirectToProviderRequest $request)
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->scopes(['instagram_basic'])->asPopup()->usingGraphVersion('v7.0')->redirect();
    }
}
```

Once the user has enter his credentials and allowed your app to have access to his data, we need to grab the access token to make calls to the fb api on his behalf.
Define the callback route in the same controller:

```
Route::get('facebook/callback','FacebookLoginController@handleProviderCallback');
```

Define the callback method in the controller:

```
 public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->input('error') == "access_denied")
        {
            return 'user has decline the authorization';
        } 
       
            $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->usingGraphVersion('v7.0')->user();
            $token = $user->token;
            $refreshToken = $user->refreshToken;
            $id = $user->getId();
    }
```

From here, your have your access token (`$token`) to call the fb api.

Please note that the user can cancel the authorization, so will probably want to catch the error in the callback. I didn't put all the error handling stuff since it can complicate the code

Comment: i will check this soon and let you know the answer just one thing is that does instagram user pass and facebook coordinates are the same cause i want to get the users instagrams posts and you in answer said the facebook acount that confused me a bit and thanks for the answer

Comment: Yes you right. Facebook has merge the instagram api into graph. You have to go throug facebook to get the instagram post. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation, I think the app secret should be used to generate the access token, kindly review this step : **Step 5: Exchange the Code for a Token** on the documentation :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started